# LaTeX text goes out of page boundaries

Tags: latex

I'm a super beginner with latex, so please be patient and don't assume I know anything, thanks!

Using Overleaf.com I'm trying to create a CV based on this template:
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/awesome-resume-cv

However, the "skills" section does not behave the way I expected it: if I write a long list of skills, the words go beyond the page limit on the right instead of starting a new line. How do I fix this?

I tried by using `\\` to end the line, but that gives a syntax error.

Thank you!

Comment: Would be good if you could append the problematic TeX lines as a code example. That would spare us to work through the template.

Comment: Some code (or like usually with latex questions, a "Minimal Working Sample") would be more helpful. Also there is a special board for latex questions on stack exchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to follow the problem you describe. In order to do that I created to sample lists of skills:

```
\cvskill
{Sample} % Category
{Sample A, Sample B, Sample C, Sample D, Sample E, Sample F, Sample G, Sample H, Sample I, Sample J, Sample K, Sample L, Sample M, Sample N, Sample O} % Skills

\cvskill
{Sample 2} % Category
{Averylongskillnamethatmayexceedthepage A, Averylongskillnamethatmayexceedthepage B, Averylongskillnamethatmayexceedthepage C, Averylongskillnamethatmayexceedthepage D, Averylongskillnamethatmayexceedthepage E, } % Skills
```

After compiling the skills section looks as follows:

[image: Sample Skills in Mentioned CV Template]

So according to my view line breaks are added correctly. In case you are annoyed by slightly overarching text items like "Sample K" you can add a `\newline` before the corresponding item to force a manual line break.

The `\` command is no 'line ending' symbol and even the command `\\` which does exactly this should not work, as the `cvskill` command internally uses a `tabular` environment, which accepts the `\newline` command but not `\\`.

In case I missed to solve your problem please provide a more extensive problem description including a valid and recreateable example! Otherwise it's very complicated to narrow down the exact issue you have.

Comment: That's exactly my problem, even though I had a much more extreme issue than "sample K" (the words were actually disappearing from view out of the page itself).
I meant to write `//` and not `/`, so the problem was simply that I used `//` instead of `/newline` to break the line.
Thank you!

Comment: Yep, that can happen if you have very long words - or words where `LaTeX` fails to hyphenate them correctly. But exactly those things would make a perfect code snippet since that would allow to either suggest commands like `\newline` or maybe trying to fix hypenation or other issues. ;)

And you are welcome. The `\\ ` and `\newline` thing is something I guess everyone stumples across at the beginning.